# Return JSON object from URL in Node.js / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, url

I'm trying to create a function which returns a JSON object from an URL.
It should work like this:

```
function getObject(url) {
  // return undefined when the url or json is invalid
  return object;
}
```

So that I can use it in this way, if I would use the following URL:

```
var object = getObject('http://ip.jsontest.com/');
console.log('My IP is: ' + object.ip)
```

The JSON from the example looks like this:

```
{"ip": "127.0.0.1"}
```

So the code above should log this:

> My IP is: 127.0.0.1

I already tried it with the request module and found this example on StackOverflow:

```
request.get({ 
  url: 'http://ip.jsontest.com/', 
  json: true, 
  headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'} }, (err, res, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err)
  } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Status:', res.statusCode)
  } else {
    // data is already parsed as JSON:
    console.log(data)
  }
})
```

The data is displayed in the console as it should, but I found no way to use the it like in the example I provided above.
Is there a way to solve this without callbacks? I read that requests are asynchronous, but I need a synchronus solution.

Comment: Node.js runs asynchronous. You could use Promises or Async/Await.

Comment: You should not want a synchronous solution. It is never necessary if you embrace asynchronous programming patterns, such as promises.

Answer (score -1):

No there is no way to do this synchronously. You could look into using the [fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) and an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) if they're supported in your environment.

For example:

```js
async function getMyIpAndDoSomething() {
  const response = await fetch("http://ip.jsontest.com/");
  const object = await response.json();

  console.log(object.ip);
}
```

Comment: it is possible to make it synchronous by using promises, wait until you get a response

Comment: That's how all asynchronous values work. You wait for the response. You can't fetch synchronously though.